# How do I Import a function from a different directory to my main code without getting a NameError?

Tags: python, function, import, path, nameerror

I'm using Python 3.8.5.
I was aiming at creating a simple addition function (and yes, I'm aware Python has an in-built one).
I created the function satisfactorily, but wasn't able to import it to the program of my choice. I keep getting NameErrors, saying that the name of my function has not been defined.
Here's the code to the function:

```
def add_func(x, y):
    sum = x + y
    sum_str = str(sum)
    print("The sum is " + sum_str)
```

And here's where the issues begin:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User_name\\Desktop\\Folder\\PYTHON\\Functions')
import addition
x = (input("Enter no. 1: "))
y = (input("Enter no. 2: "))
add_func(x,y)
```

I have an **init** file in the folder named Functions.
I've scoured the web for hours searching for a solution to my problem, but have been unable to find one that:
a) I can understand (still learning Python)
b) Has worked

I'd really appreciate it if somebody could guide me on how to fix this issue, and explain to me what I've done wrong (dumb it down as much as possible)

Comment: So where's `add_func` supposedly located?

Comment: You wrote `import sys` and used it with `sys.path.append...`. Simply do the same with the addition module.

Comment: I used sys.path.append to specify which the directory wherein add_func was located...so I'm pretty sure thats not an issue...the issue was the NameError, which I've gotten an answer to...but I really do appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If addition is the name of your .py file, and it has been successfully imported, then to use your add_func function you would need to write:

`addition.add_func(x, y)`

If you wanted to be able to use it without the addition., you can change the import statement to:

`from addition import add_func`